# Illegal back reference when trying to delete \1

Tags: regular-expression, search-replace

I have a bunch of expressions (matlab anonymous functions) of the form, for example

```
`f\^I = @(x,y,z) x^y + z`,
`g1\^I\^I = @(z,b,c) z^b + c`
```

(where `\^I` means a tab, but I can't just write that in this editor)

I want to build a macro that removes the `\^I = @` and the stuff after the ), to produce

```
f(x,y,z) 
g1(z,b,c)
```

I'm stuck on the first part of this macro.  It seems that this should work:

```
:g/[0-9a-zA-Z]\(\^I.\{-}=.\{-}@\)/s/\1//
```

but for some reason I get the error `E65: Illegal back reference`

Could somebody please explain how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `\1` as a back reference to what matched in a *separate* pattern match.

I see you're using the pattern in the `:g` capture group to match the location and use a capture group to pick the part you want to replace, then hoping you can use a separate `:s` and refer to that group as `\1`, but you can't really do that.

You could set up a capture group with the part that is supposed to *remain* and refer back to that capture group in your replacement in order to *keep* it.

```
:g/\([0-9a-zA-Z]\)\(\^I.\{-}=.\{-}@\)/s//\1/
```

Note that `\1` now refers to the character *before* the match and that the `\1` is part of the replacement. When you use an empty pattern in a `:s`, it repeats the previously used pattern, in other words, matches exactly the same as the `:g` did.

Note that you don't actually need the `\2` capture group anymore, since you're not using it anywhere... So you can drop those:

```
:g/\([0-9a-zA-Z]\)\^I.\{-}=.\{-}@/s//\1/
```

Finally, instead of using a capture group, you can use `\zs` to mark the start of the match, in which case you can match just the `\^I = @` part, even if you're including other characters for context, and simply replace them by an empty string:

```
:g/[0-9a-zA-Z]\zs\^I.\{-}=.\{-}@/s///
```

Comment: Thanks @filbranden,    the last line did just what I wanted.     For some reason I couldn't get the first two to work, but the basic idea was helpful.      Also, in my original post, I wrote `=\{-}@` when I should have written =`.\{-}@`   Looks like you cut and pasted my error.   I tried to edit your answer, but it wouldn't accept a single dot edit!

Comment: @LeoSimon I edited to include the `=.\{-}@` as you mentioned, take another look. Yeah I didn't understand exactly if you meant `\^I` to represent a tab character... Note that you can also use a literal `\t` to match a tab in a pattern, that would be cleaner. (But since I didn't understand exactly what you were after, I avoided changing that part.)

Answer (score 1):

Here’s two ways to accomplish the whole thing:

- A macro `qq0f`<kbd>Tab</kbd>`df@%lDq`
- A command `:normal! 0f`<kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>`df@%lDq`

You can use a range with`:normal` to apply to multiple lines. In fact you can even do `:normal! @q` after recording the macro. Normally that’s useless, but if you have a range it’s much easier than running each `@q` yourself.

---

The essential bit is to find a recipe for each line you're interesting in changing. To me, that recipe looks like this:

1. Find the first tab from the start of the line (`0f`<kbd>Tab</kbd>).
2. Delete up to and including the following `@` character (`df@`).
3. Delete everything after the closing parenthesis for the current opening parenthesis (`%lD`).

The rest is packaging it up to make it easy to repeat. You may know that `.` repeats the last edit, but if you perform that sequence and then hit `.` it will only repeat the `D` command! So we use a macro (`:help complex-repeat`): record into the `q` register (`qq`), do the actions, and stop recording `q`. Then replay with `@q` on any lines you care about (more on that in a second).

Alternately, since it's a fairly straightforward set of commands, you can just use `:normal!` with the commands and a range: the commands will be processed once for each line in the range.

#### On replaying macros

- You can hit `@q` to replay a macro in register `q`. After that, `@@` will replay the last-used macro, which makes it easy to type. Press `@qj@@j@@j@@…`.
- If you end a macro with a command to go to the next line to edit, you can just mash `@@` (or use a count). Press `@@@@@@@@…` or `<n>@@`.
- At that point, you *might* be able to write a recursive macro, which moves to the next line *and invokes itself*. Then one invocation will do the whole change. This is a tricky technique, but a fun one. (Tips: clear the register before recording; make sure you have a way to cause an error at the end to stop the macro; use Control-C if something looks stuck.)
- You can run a macro on a range with `:normal! @q`. You can also get `:global` and `:vglobal` in there, too. This avoids recursive macro shenanigans at the price of requiring your patterns (or ranges) to be very precise.

Comment: Hi @DBenknoble, I'm afraid I couldn't follow you abstract macro suggestion.    Would you mind providing a concrete example, please?

Comment: @LeoSimon does my edit help?

Comment: @DBenKnoble, Wow, thanks for the detailed explanation.     It looks daunting but I'll work through it as soon as I get a chance, looks very powerful!

Comment: @LeoSimon it gets less daunting—it’s a nice orthogonal extension to every-day editing commands (at least, if you use vim every day). It’s occasionally more natural to me than a complex regex